# How do I change the text font, size and colour of all the different texts in the R package, Likert?

Tags: r, text, fonts, colors

At the moment, there is only features in place to change the font of the percentages, but I would like to change the font, size and colour of all text in the Likert package's bar plot. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it pretty much how you would any `ggplot`: by adding `theme()` options. (At least, how you'd fine-tune things anyway.)

Using the example data from `?likert`

```
library("likert")
data(pisaitems)
items29 <- pisaitems[,substr(names(pisaitems), 1,5) == 'ST25Q']
names(items29) <- c("Magazines", "Comic books", "Fiction",
                    "Non-fiction books", "Newspapers")
l29 <- likert(items29)
summary(l29)

p1 <- plot(l29) # assign the plot to an object

# modify some stuff
p1 + theme(text = element_text(size = rel(6), colour = "red"),
           axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "blue",
                                      family = "Courier"))
```

In general, you can look at the return of a theme call, e.g. `theme_bw()` to see all the things that can be modified this way. Anything that is set in the `plot.likert` code will (e.g. the y axis text colour) will need to be explicitly modified, it won't inherit from the more general `text`. If it's mostly text you're modifying, `?element_text` will probably be helpful.

Also note that if you're using RStudio setting the font family may not change the plot in the plot window, but it will work if you export the plot as a PDF. (At least for me, on Windows.)

If you want to change the text that is part of the plot (set by `geom_text`), you'll probably need to actually hack the function. It's [all on github](https://github.com/jbryer/likert/blob/master/R/plot.likert.bar.r), so just make your own fork of the package.

Comment: That was so quick, thank you. I'm on a bit of a deadline at work so don't have too long to figure out how all of this works. What about changing the interpolated colours from neutral.color.ramp to setting all 5 colours individually. Any idea how that would work? Thanks again

Comment: Nvm, figured it out. +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"))